# usando java y primefaces al momento de actulizar el primefaces de 5.0 a 10.0.0 se borra el nombre de mi proyecto en la URL

Tags: java, url, primefaces

En mi proyecto de investigacion estoy usando java y primefaces al momento de actulizar el primefaces de 5.0 a 10.0.0 se borra el nombre de mi proyecto en la URL como puedo solucionar esto?.

Este el archivo POM

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el menu el cual tiene las URL en base de datos al momento de dar clic me lleva a la url que esta en la base de datos pero se borra el nombre del proyecto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es la base de datos con la url

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

podría colocarle sin / pero igual me presenta error, podría colocarle en la base de datos toda la ruta junto con el nombre de proyecto pero no es adecuado ya que si el usuario cambia de nombre de proyecto tendríamos que cambiar mas de 100 url lo cual no es muy bien.

y este es el error que me presenta [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]